# Copy data from 1 data-set to another on the basis of Unique ID

Tags: python, pandas

I am matching two large data-sets and trying to perform update,remove and create operations on original data-set by comparing it with other data-set. How can I update 2 or 3 column out of 10 of original data-set and keep other column's value same as before?

I tried merge but no avail.

**Original data:**

```
id | full_name   |   date
1  | John        |   02-23-2006
2  | Paul Elbert |   09-29-2001
3  | Donag       |   11-12-2013
4  | Tom Holland |   06-17-2016
```

**other data:**

```
id | full_name  |   date
1  | John       |   02-25-2018
2  | Paul       |   03-09-2001
3  | Donag      |   07-09-2017
4  | Tom        |   05-09-2016
```

Is it possible to update date column of original data on the basis of ID?

Comment: Have you looked at: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html ?

Comment: My data is not identical.... e.g data-set 1 has 5690 rows and 8 columns and other has 5793 rows and 17 columns.

Comment: I want to compare on the basis of unique ID when both data-set ID's match then update the date column full_name column.

Comment: well it is possible, but based on what aspect of ID you want to update, when the dates are different? or if they have new/different name ? or if the certain ID of a column has different value? Please elaborate

Comment: When ID match code update all values in date column without changing any value in name column of original data set

Comment: @Shewert Gottes how your expected output looks like?

Answer (score 0):

answering your question :
"When ID match code update all values in date column without changing any value in name column of original data set"

```
original = pd.DataFrame({'id':['1','2'],'full_name':['John','Paul Elbert'],'date':
['02-23-2006','09-29-2001']})
other = pd.DataFrame({'id':['1','2'],'full_name':['John','Paul'],'date':['02-25-2018','03-09-2001']})
original = original[['id','full_name']].merge(other[['id','date']],on='id')
print(original)

  id    full_name        date
0  1         John  02-25-2018
1  2  Paul Elbert  03-09-2001
```